# How do I input these types of voltages in LTspice?

Tags: ltspice

How can I input:

1. 7Vpp 2kHz 70% duty cycle pulse train with 2V DC offset
2. 9Vpp 3kHz sinusoid with no DC offset
3. 3Vpp 5kHz sawtooth with no DC offset

I am not sure how to put the percentages into the directive and what "Vpp" means and where to put it. I also don't know how to make the wave form "sawtooth" on the input. Showing the exact places to put the values would be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest that you for 1) look at the vpulse, possibly in series with a vdc for 2) look at vsine for 3) you can make with the vpulse (just use longer trise and tfall) or you can use a vpwl where you can enter time:voltage points. General remark: Your 1) and 3) are specified in frequency while the sources that you need to make these need to be set with **time** information so convert 1) and 3) to what the signal looks like **over time**.

Comment: Note that since you're in a simulator, you can do whatever you like. So make a new schematic and create these signal (no need to get them exactly right the first time) using the sources I suggested. Then **just simulate** and see what you get. Also: read the manual!

Comment: Besides what @Bimpelrekkie said, if you don't know what `Vpp` means, you have a different problem.

Comment: What have you tried so far in term of looking up terms, reading the manual, checking examples and testing around in LTspice?